# How to provide more than one whatsapp numbers to whatsapp Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I am using below code to send whatsapp message through intent and it works fine.

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent whatsAppIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
try
  {
     String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+91XXXXXXXXXX&text=Hello, Folks";
     whatsAppIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
     whatsAppIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
     if (whatsAppIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null)
     {
        context.startActivity(whatsAppIntent);
     }
     else
     {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp Not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  }catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp Not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now I want to provide more than one numbers for same Uri. How could I achieve it. Other ways to the same are welcomed.

Comment: I i do not think the API allows this however you can create a group with the targets numbers and use `chatId` instead of `phone` when you're calling the API.